# Ignore first line on csv parse Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I am using the code from [this tutorial](http://satishonrails.wordpress.com/2007/07/18/how-to-import-csv-file-in-rails/) to parse a CSV file and add the contents to a database table. How would I ignore the first line of the CSV file? The controller code is below:

```
def csv_import 
  @parsed_file=CSV::Reader.parse(params[:dump][:file])
  n = 0
  @parsed_file.each  do |row|
    s = Student.new
    s.name = row[0]
    s.cid = row[1]
    s.year_id = find_year_id_from_year_title(row[2])
    if s.save
      n = n+1
      GC.start if n%50==0
    end
    flash.now[:message] = "CSV Import Successful, #{n} new students added to the database."
  end
  redirect_to(students_url)
end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
@parsed_file.each_with_index  do |row, i|
  next if i == 0
  ....
```

Comment: I downvoted this because this isn't very good self-documenting code. The declarative style of passing `headers: true` in the options to the parser is much clearer.

Answer (score 46):

This question kept popping up when i was searching for how to skip the first line with the CSV / FasterCSV libraries, so here's the solution *that* if you end up here.

the solution is...
`CSV.foreach("path/to/file.csv",{:headers=>:first_row}) do |row|`

HTH.

Comment: You can also pass hash `{:headers => true}` as second parameter. This works also.

Answer (score 4):

If you identify your first line as headers then you get back a `Row` object instead of a simple `Array`.

When you grab cell values, it seems like you need to use `.fetch("Row Title")` on the `Row` object.

This is what I came up with. I'm skipping `nil` with my `if` conditional.

`CSV.foreach("GitHubUsersToAdd.csv",{:headers=>:first_row}) do |row|
  username = row.fetch("GitHub Username")
  if username
    puts username.inspect
  end
end`

Answer (score 3):

Using this simple code, you can read a CSV file and ignore the first line which is the header or field names:

```
CSV.foreach(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), filepath), headers: true) do |row|
    puts row.inspect
end
```

You can do what ever you want with `row`. Don't forget `headers: true`

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'csv'
csv_content =<<EOF
lesson_id,user_id
5,3
69,95
EOF

parse_1 = CSV.parse csv_content
parse_1.size # => 3  # it treats all lines as equal data

parse_2 = CSV.parse csv_content, headers:true
parse_2.size # => 2  # it ignores the first line as it's header

parse_1
# => [["lesson_id", "user_id"], ["5", "3"], ["69", "95"]]     
parse_2
# => #<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:3>
```

here where it's the  fun part

```
parse_1.each do |line|
  puts line.inspect        # the object is array
end
# ["lesson_id", "user_id"]
# ["5", " 3"]
# ["69", " 95"]


parse_2.each do |line|
  puts line.inspect        # the object is `CSV::Row` objects
end
# #<CSV::Row "lesson_id":"5" "user_id":" 3">
# #<CSV::Row "lesson_id":"69" "user_id":" 95">
```

So therefore I can do

```
parse_2.each do |line|
  puts "I'm processing Lesson #{line['lesson_id']} the User #{line['user_id']}"
end
# I'm processing Lesson 5 the User 3
# I'm processing Lesson 69 the User 95
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data_rows_only = csv.drop(1)
```

will do it

```
csv.drop(1).each do |row|
  # ...
end
```

will loop it