# Ignore header line when parsing CSV file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, csv

How can the header line of the CSV file be ignored in ruby on rails while doing the CSV parsing!! Any ideas

Comment: What exactly is your question? To skip the Headerline simply start at line 1 instead of 0

Comment: btw, don't forget that you will need the header to identify the content of the CVS. Otherwise you just have data without knowing what exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to above question. Here is the way i have done it in ruby 1.9.X.

```
csv_contents = CSV.parse(File.read(file))
csv_contents.slice!(0)
csv=""
csv_contents.each do |content|
    csv<<CSV.generate_line(content)
end
```

Comment: `File.read` slurps the whole thing into memory. I'd avoid this on a large CSV file.

Answer (score 26):

If you're using ruby 1.8.X and FasterCSV, it has a '**headers**' option:

```
csv = FasterCSV.parse(your_csv_file, {:headers => true}) #or false if you do want to read them
```

If you're using ruby 1.9.X, the default library is basically FasterCSV, so you can just do the following:

```
csv = CSV.parse(your_csv_file, {headers: true})
```

Comment: watch-out as `CSV.parse  your_csv_content` and  `CSV.parse your_csv_content, headers: true` returns different objects . First is array of arrays, second is array of `CSV::Row` objects    http://stackoverflow.com/a/37856698/473040

Answer (score 6):

```
csv = CSV.read("file")

csv.shift # <-- kick out the first line

csv # <-- the results that you want
```

Answer (score 1):

Easier way I have found is by doing this:

```
file = CSV.open('./tmp/sample_file.csv', { :headers => true })
# <#CSV io_type:File io_path:"./tmp/sample_file.csv" encoding:UTF-8 lineno:0 col_sep:"," row_sep:"\n" quote_char:"\"" headers:true>

file.each do |row|
 puts row
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest one worked for me. You can read a CSV file and ignore its first line which is the header or field names using `headers: true`:

```
CSV.foreach(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), filepath), headers: true) do |row|
    puts row.inspect
end
```

You can do what ever you want with `row`. Don't forget `headers: true`

Answer (score 0):

To skip the header *without* the `headers` option (since that has the side-effect of returning `CSV::Row` rather than `Array`) while still processing a line at a time:

```rb
File.open(path, 'r') do |io|
  io.readline
  csv = CSV.new(io, headers: false)
  while row = csv.shift do
    # process row
  end
end
```