# How can I skip the header row when reading a CSV in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, csv

Ruby's [`CSV`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-foreach) class makes it pretty easy to iterate over each row:

```
CSV.foreach(file) { |row| puts row }
```

However, this always includes the header row, so I'll get as output:

```
header1, header2
foo, bar
baz, yak
```

I don't want the headers though. Now, when I call …

```
CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true)
```

I get this result:

```
#<CSV::Row:0x10112e510
    @header_row = false,
    attr_reader :row = [
        [0] [
            [0] "header1",
            [1] "foo"
        ],
        [1] [
            [0] "header2",
            [1] "bar"
        ]
    ]
>
```

Of course, because the documentation says:

> This setting causes #shift to return rows as CSV::Row objects instead of Arrays

But, **how can I skip the header row, returning the row as a simple array?** I don't want the complicated `CSV::Row` object to be returned.

I definitely don't want to do this:

```
first = true
CSV.foreach(file) do |row|
  if first
    puts row
    first = false
  else
    # code for other rows
  end
end
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/37856698/473040

Answer (score 16):

Look at [**#shift**](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-i-shift) from CSV Class:

*The primary read method for wrapped Strings and IOs, a single row is pulled from the data source, parsed and returned as an Array of fields (if header rows are not used)*

An Example:

```
require 'csv'

# CSV FILE
# name, surname, location
# Mark, Needham, Sydney
# David, Smith, London

def parse_csv_file_for_names(path_to_csv)
  names = []  
  csv_contents = CSV.read(path_to_csv)
  csv_contents.shift
  csv_contents.each do |row|
    names << row[0]
  end
  return names
end
```

Comment: CSV.read returns ans Array and #shift is default methods for array. and correctfully very usefull here.

Comment: You can also iterate using `each_with_index` and check which line index you're on. A `next if (i == 0)` would skip the first line for index `i`.

Comment: @tadman Feel free to post that as a separate answer – looks viable.

Comment: Is this more memory intensive because you're saving the entire file contents into a variable, as opposed to reading line by line when doing foreach?

Answer (score 16):

You might want to consider `CSV.parse(csv_file, { :headers => false })` and passing a block, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936204/ignore-header-line-when-parsing-csv-file)

Comment: note: this only works since Ruby 1.9

Comment: additional note: if you're using < Ruby 1.9 then you really should update.

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me. I had to do `CSV.parse(csv_file, headers: :first_row, return_headers: false)` to get it working.

Comment: @ocodo Based and Redpilled.

Answer (score 9):

A cool way to ignore the headers is to read it as an array and ignore the first row:

```
data = CSV.read("dataset.csv")[1 .. -1]
# => [["first_row", "with data"],
      ["second_row", "and more data"],
      ...
      ["last_row", "finally"]]
```

The problem with the `:headers => false` approach is that `CSV` won't try to read the first row as a header, but will consider it part of the data. So, basically, you have a useless first row.

Comment: Nice to see a few options, but keep in mind if your CSV file is large, this isn't very memory-friendly relative to the other answers. Also, it's exactly the same answer as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20623072/6243352) -- best to post once.