# importing data into a postgresql from csv file- best way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, csv, import

Hi I have data in a csv file format that Id like to import into my postgresql. The postgresql would be used in my rails app as a prepopulated db. I realize rails uses a ORM . So I was wondering if its good to import data into the db like this.

If not how should I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, for bulk loading you'll want to use the [`COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) interface or, if you can afford downtime and have truly monsterous amounts of data to load, [`pg_bulkload`](http://pgbulkload.projects.postgresql.org/).

`COPY` can be client- or server-side. For client-side `COPY` your client needs to support it. `libpq` does, as does the `psql` client. PgJDBC also supports `COPY` from client side. I don't know if Ruby's database interface does, but I doubt it. If it doesn't you can use server-side `COPY` if you have appropriate access permissions on the server, or you can shell out to `psql` to do the bulk import using the psql `\copy` command.

Comment: You can bulk load from the Ruby side via the native database connection (that ActiveRecord uses under the covers).  It works quite well, but is more fiddly than using AR.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is largely answered by the sample code in this question - [Ignore first line on csv parse Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818669/ignore-first-line-on-csv-parse-rails)

I don't have the power to flag this question as a duplicate however.

Comment: Yes but that post is using a gem to parse csv. I was wondering if I can use a migration tool to accomplish this?